# Function "reencode-output-port" does not work properly in Racket

Tags: racket

I have to converts character encoding when write to a file, but I when use fuction "reencode-output-port", the last part of the string will not be written into the file.

For example, I run this piece of code:

```
(call-with-output-file "test.txt" (lambda (out)
  (display "abc"  (reencode-output-port out "gbk"))) #:exists 'truncate)
```

File test.txt does not contain anything.

When I write string long enough to the file, the last part always lost.

Is there any problem about my codes?

I have realized that I didn't close the new file port. The correct code is:

```
(call-with-output-file "test.txt" (lambda (out)
 (let [(re-out (reencode-output-port out "gbk"))] (display "abc" re-out)
   (close-output-port re-out)))
 #:exists 'truncate)
```

That's, binding the new file port to re-out, and close it when done.

But I am just wondering why call-with-output-file does not contain an encoding parameter? I use the call-with-output-file avoid a close action, now I have to face another one.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
(call-with-output-file "test.txt" (lambda (out)
  (current-output-port (reencode-output-port (current-output-port) "gbk"))
  (display "abc") 
  #:exists 'truncate))
```

Also what happens if you use a other encodings than `gbk` ?

Comment: Thank you, But it's not what I meant.

Comment: But does it work? If so, we at least now that the library doing the encoding is loaded correctly.

Comment: I have confirmed that "reencode-output-port" worked properly, the problem is I didn't close the new output port. I have described the solution in my post (edited after post).